# Update filepath to footer when saving

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have an assignment for work that when saving a file to a specific place like d:\documents\here that the filepath appears in the footer. I found code where only the name appears, not the file path, but when I saved again the name did not update.

Here is the code.

```
Sub AddTextBoxDateFilename() ' Adds a text box with date and filename to each slide ' You must first save the presentation at least once before using this
    Dim oSl As Slide
    Dim oSh As Shape

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides ' do we already have a filename/date text box? If do, use it: On Error Resume Next Set oSh = oSl.Shapes("FilenameAndDate") On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

        If oSh Is Nothing Then  ' no text box there already, create one

            ' change the position and formatting to suit your needs:
            Set oSh = oSl.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 0, 510, 720, 28.875)

            With oSh

                .Name = "FilenameAndDate"

                .TextFrame.WordWrap = msoTrue
                With .TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat
                    .LineRuleWithin = msoTrue
                    .SpaceWithin = 1
                    .LineRuleBefore = msoTrue
                    .SpaceBefore = 0.5
                    .LineRuleAfter = msoTrue
                    .SpaceAfter = 0
                End With

                With .TextFrame.TextRange.Font
                    .NameAscii = "Arial"
                    .Size = 18
                    .Bold = msoFalse
                    .Italic = msoFalse
                    .Underline = msoFalse
                    .Shadow = msoFalse
                    .Emboss = msoFalse
                    .BaselineOffset = 0
                    .AutorotateNumbers = msoFalse
                    .Color.SchemeColor = ppForeground
                End With
            End With    ' shape

        End If  ' osh is nothing

        ' now we know there's a shape by the correct name so
        Set oSh = oSl.Shapes("FilenameAndDate")
        With oSh.TextFrame.TextRange
            .Text = ActivePresentation.FullName & vbTab
        End With

        Set oSh = Nothing
    Next ' slide
NormalExit:
    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox ("There was a problem:" & vbCrLf & Err.Description)
    Resume NormalExit
End Sub
```

Comment: You will need to use the PowerPoint [Application Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff746876(v=office.14).aspx). Make sure you read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff746018(v=office.14).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

There are several file properties built into the PowerPoint OM (Object Model). In the line where the .FullName property is being written to the text box you can set the text to what you need.

To find the property, type this in the Immediate window (Ctrl+G if it isn't visible):

```
?ActivePresentation.
```

As soon as you type the dot, a list of properties and methods will be displayed by IntelliSense. You'll see .Name and .Path. Try them and see if the format is what you need. If not, you'll need to get the one closest to what you want and modify the string before writing to your text box by changing the .FullName line.

Regarding the updating, VBA is an event driven environment which means your macro needs and event to fire in order for it to be told to run. That can be as simple as a user pressing Alt+F8 and selecting your macro to run. If you want the macro to automatically run on the event "save file" then you'll need to set up application events in PowerPoint with a class module and initialisation procedure. Google "PowerPoint application events" to find out how to do that.

Finally, adding the same object to multiple slides is best done using the slide master where you can do it in one place instead of every slide. That way, your code can be simplified and the user can't accidentally (or deliberately) modify your special footer text box. You can find that here (assuming your template only has one slide master):

```
ActivePresentation.Designs(1).SlideMaster
```